# Android Pictures links from Db using base adapter

Tags: android, database, gridview, baseadapter, bitmapsource

So em, first time here asking questions, I am developing an android app, where I have one fragment with gridview of images.  I am using a database to hold the image URL's and converting them to bitmaps using a picture adapter.

How do I either extact all the strings from a column called COLUMN_IMAGElINK to an array of Strings, or send my db strings to my picture adapter class??

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking is [here](http://androidsurya.blogspot.com/2012/11/insert-and-retrieve-image-from-sqlite.html).

Comment: No, blobs can become messy when dealing with large numbers, I have a string to the link of the picture, its just trying to extract the strings to send to my working picture adapter so it can be converted to bitmap